# Problem with citation biblatex

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have a problem with citations using biblatex. I don't have an extra file, my bibliography is in the end of the code like down below. But when I write for example \cite{tao2011introduction} it doesn't work. What could be the problem??

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}

\bibitem{tao2011introduction}{Tao, T. An introduction to measure theory. (American Mathematical Society Providence, RI,2011)}

\bibitem[2]{folland1999real}{Folland, G. Real analysis: modern techniques and their applications. (John Wiley \& Sons,1999)}

\end{otherlanguage}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example if I write \cite{tao2011introduction} the result after the compile will be [tao2011introduction] and not [1].

Comment: Did you run bibtex or biber on your document -- either explicitly or else as part of some command such as pdflatexmk that includes a run of bibtex or biber along with multiple runs of (pdf)latex?

Comment: I use overleaf. How can I do this?

Comment: If you manually write your `thebibliography` as shown in the question directly into your `.tex` file you do not need to run BibTeX at all. (Even if you had to run BibTeX, you would not have to worry about that since you are using Overleaf, which uses the awesome `latexmk` script that runs BibTeX automatically if required.) It is not clear what the problem is and what causes it from the code shared so far. Even though it is extremely unusual to have a `\begin{otherlanguage}...\end{otherlanguage}` within a `thebibliography` I could not reproduce an error with your code.

Comment: You will have to share more about what you are doing in the form of a fully compilable example document. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.

Comment: I removed the `biblatex` tag since your are using `thebibliography` which is incompatible with `biblatex`.